# Firefox onchange not calling function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a form that contains input:

`<input onchange="checkDomain(true); return false;" type="text" id="dsearch" value="" name="domain" maxlength="30"/>`

Which works just fine in Opera, Chrome and IE - but Firefox and Safari are having problems with calling the function `checkDomain()`. I added a line into the function for debugging:

```
function checkDomain(check) 
{
console.log('checkDomain() called!'); 
// do rest of the stuff...
}
```

So, Chrome/Opera/IE calls the function with no problem after you enter text and click somewhere else - but Firefox/Safari doesn't. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Hi! Your callback function should be called in firefox once you leave the field, like the blur event... But it won't be called at each type-ins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot remember where I read it, but you should use `.keydown()`/`.keyup()`/`.keypress()` (whatever suits your needs) instead of onchange. At least for `input[type=text]`.

you can use `.blur()` and `.focus` for their respective purposes too.

Seeing this in your question: "after you enter text and click somewhere else", makes me conclude you need the .blur() function.

```
   $("input[type=text]").blur(function(){
       console.log('checkDomain() called!')
   });
```

Comment: While Mihai Iorga excellent answer boiles down to the same, I think it's better to group your event calls in a JS file instead of adding them to your html elements. It makes for easier maintainable code.
just my two cents ...

Comment: Yes, but the OP did not mntioned any jQuery here so plain javascript here.

Comment: This does the job! Thanks! (jQuery is JS lib, so definitely jQuery allowed)

Comment: @PopArtStudioDev you should add jQuery tag next time.

Comment: Ok, sorry, will do that next time. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

maybe `onblur` is best for this:

```
<input onblur="checkDomain(true); return false;" type="text" id="dsearch" value="" name="domain" maxlength="30"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem happens when you change the behavior of your input keypress and key down.

You need to manually call the `onchange` trigger to fire it.

As an example consider you have a jQuery function for your inputs which do some stuff when user clicks on keyboard.

You need to call `input.trigger("onchange");` to make sure the onchange is fired after `keypress` and `keydown`

```
/**
 * Keyboard Manager
 */
(function($) {
    $.fn.inputManager = function(options) {
        };
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        // The key down event only use to manage key board language changes
        var keyDown = function(e) {
           //Do something
        };

        var keyPress = function(e) {
            //Do something
        };

        return this.each(function() {
            var input = $(this);

            //The Firefox dose not trigger the input onchange when you change keypress and key down
            //functions. So manually call it!
            input.keypress(function(e) {
                keyPress(e);
                input.trigger("onchange");
            });
            input.keydown(function(e) {
                keyDown(e);
                input.trigger("onchange");
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```